# Solve for N from input string

Tags: code-golf, string, math

## Challenge :

Your job is to find the given number `N`.

---

## Input :

You will be given a string in the following form:

```
dN ± Y = X
```

Where:

```
d, N, X, Y are all numbers with d , X , Y being integers (not decimals).
```

---

## Output :

Solve the equation and output the value of `N` rounded. Round up if decimal is greater than or equal to `0.5` and round down if less than `0.5`

---

## Examples :

```
Input                  Output
 N + 1 = 3        ---> 2
 N - 1 = 5        ---> 6
2N + 1 = 3        ---> 1 
2N + 1 = 4        ---> 2
```

---

## Winning criteria :

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest code in each language wins.

---

## Notes :

- Answer must be rounded it cannot be a float
- Whitespace do not matter. You can have every element in the string separated by white space if you want or if you don't want leave it as it is.
- You do not need to check for invalid input. i.e. All inputs will be strings in the given format.

---

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76254/discussion-on-question-by-muhammad-salman-solve-for-n-from-input-string).

Comment: @Mego : I have (hopefully) made it more clear. Can you kindly take a look and open it?

Comment: @MuhammadSalman I'll leave both the original and add the alternative `[-128,127]` range answer then. (And I will delete some of my answers now, thanks for answering them.)

Comment: Can `d` , `X` , and `Y` be negative? what is the maximum value that needs to be handled?

Comment: @TaylorScott : If you want you can implement that.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>88</s> <s>74</s> 70 bytes

-14 bytes thanks to [Chas Brown](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/69880/chas-brown).
-4 bytes thanks to [Sunny Patel](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58557/sunny-patel).

```python
d,w,Y,_,X=input().split()
print round((int(X)-int(w+Y))/float(d[:-1]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfnJ@SaqukpPQ/RadcJ1InXifCNjOvoLREQ1OvuCAnE0hzFRRl5pUoFOWX5qVoaACZGhGauiCqXDtSU1M/LSc/sUQjJdpK1zBWU/M/0CgurtSK1GQFkMlaJv@VDP0UtBUMFWwVjJW4QBxdMMcUyDFCloFzTJQA)

Comment: @ovs : He he broke it. If I remove even a single space bam. It blows up. This is whitespace sensitive.

Comment: @MuhammadSalman This was the case before. This solution requires at least one space between the different parts. If this is not allowed I will delete my answer.

Comment: @ovs: Na it is perfectly alright.

Answer (score 4):

under the assumption (according to comments) that we deal only with digits

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 30 bytes

*thanks for @Rick Hitchcock for pointing out i can use 1 instead of space (reduces 13 bytes

```javascript
x=>(x[3]+x[5]-x[9])/-x[0]+.5|0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@7/C1k6jIto4Vrsi2jRWtyLaMlZTH0gZxGrrmdYY/E/OzyvOz0nVy8lP10jTUDL0U9BWMFSwVTBW0rS1NdLkwpTXBcubguTNMOSNUPQbairgVGACseA/AA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <del>64</del> 63 bytes

Using [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval)

```python
d,w,Y,_,X=input().split()
print-eval('('+w+Y+'-'+X+')/'+d[:-1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfnJ@SaqukpPQ/RadcJ1InXifCNjOvoLREQ1OvuCAnE0hzFRRl5pXoppYl5mioa6hrl2tHaqvrqmtHaKtr6qtrp0Rb6RrGav4HmsGVWpGarAAyUcvkv5Khn4K2gqGCrYKxEheIowvmmAI5RsgycI6JEgA)

Saved 1 byte thanks to [Keyu Gan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59292/keyu-gan)

Answer (score 2):

## Java 10, <s>111</s> 94 (or 92) bytes

```java
s->{var a=s.split("N|=");return(int)((new Float(a[2])-new Float(a[1]))/new Float(a[0])+.5);}
```

Input is in the format `dN±Y=X` (without any spaces) instead of `dN ± Y = X`.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##jU@xbsIwEN35ilMmn1DchpYpMiNbszCiDFfjVgbjRPYlFYJ8e@qGDExtpbvhvXt6792ResqPh9OoHcUIb2T9dQFgPZvwQdpA9QMnArTYcbD@EyKWiRzSpolMbDVU4EHBGPPNtacApKKMrbMssuqmMiyD4S54kXxQCG@@YOsaYkH7VY35Iy5qxKdH4rnGpVxjOYzlPbHt3l1KnIP7xh7gnHrP7fY14b3z7hLZnGXTsWzThZ0XXmqRFdWyUC8ZTl/8JssLtf5Ttvqf2yR7nWXDYhi/AQ)

2 more bytes could be saved if the numbers are never outside the `[-128, 127]` range, in which case the last and one of the two first `Float` can be changed to `Byte`.
[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##jU8xbsMwDNzzCsKTiMBqnTaToQ4dutVLxsADq6iBUkU2JNpFkPrtruJ4yJQWIIc7Hu6OB@opP@y@Ru0oRngn688LAOvZhE/SBqoLnAjQYsPB@j1ELBM5pE0TmdhqqMCDgjHmL@eeApCKMrbOssiqH5VhGQx3wYvkg0J48w1vriEWtF3VmF/w64lNgkWN@HCDH2tcyjWWw1he89ruw6W8ObZv7A6OqfXcbVsTXhtvTpHNUTYdyzZd2HnhpRZZUS0L9ZTh9MM9WV6o9Z@y1f/cJtnzLBsWw/gL)

**Explanation:**

```java
s->{                             // Method with String parameter and integer return-type
  var a=s.split("N|=");          //  And split by "N" or "=" to a String-array
  return(int)((new Float(a[2])   //  Return the third number (after the equal sign),
               -new Float(a[1])) //   minus the second number (including leading +/-),
              /new Float(a[0])   //   divided by the first number
         +.5);}                  //  Rounded by using `(int)(R + 0.5)`
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) v2.0a0, 20 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
q/N|=/ f
o!-Uo)r!÷ r
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=2.0a0&code=cS9OfD0vIGYKbyEtVW8pciH3IHI&input=IjJOKzE9NCI)

```
q/N|=/ f\no!-Uo)r!÷ r     :Implicit input of string U
                          : e.g. "2N+1=4"  "N+1=4"
q                         :Split on
 /N|=/                    :  "N" or "="
                          > ["2","+1","4"] ["","+1","4"]
       f                  :Filter (removes the first element if the string started with "N")
                          > ["2","+1","4"] ["+1","4"]
        \n                :Reassign to U
             Uo           :Pop last element (X)
                          > "4"            "4"
          o               :Modify last element (Y)
           !-             :X-Y
                          > ["2",3]        [3]
                r         :Reduce by
                 !÷       :  Inverse division
                          > 1.5            3
                    r     :Round
                          > 2              3
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <del>54</del> 46 bytes

```
Round[ToExpression[""<>(#/."="->"-")]~Root~1]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7Pyi/NC8lOiTftaKgKLW4ODM/L1pJycZOQ1lfT8lWSddOSVdJM7YuKD@/pM4wVu1/QFFmXkl0WnS1kpGSjpIfEGsDsSEQ2wKxiVJtbOx/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 44 bytes

```javascript
x=>([m,a,r]=x.split(/N|=/),r-a)/(+m||1)+.5|0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fc27DoMgGEDhvU/BJoSb0NKl@X0EXqDpQKw2NigGjHHg3enSwaSX/cs5T7e61MZhXvgU7l3poWzQ4OvIHIs32ESa/bBgaTNIwiJ3RGI65qwIFSbXpQ1TCr4TPjxwjytkqYJjRRAAII3I5fABuALzBucvQO8L6hc4/Vmo2lID2uxIeQE)

Or, for only single-digit numbers:

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 36 bytes

```javascript
([m,,o,a,,r])=>-(o+a-r)/(+m||1)+.5|0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@18jOldHJ18nUUenKFbT1k5XI187UbdIU19DO7emxlBTW8@0xuB/cn5ecX5Oql5OfrpGmoa6gp@2oa2xuqaCra2tgpGCpjUXhgJdQ1tTqAIzLAqMkE0wxKXABMmK/wA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Befunge-93 (FBBI)](https://github.com/catseye/FBBI), <s>34</s> 26 bytes

```
&~$~90p0&X&-2*\/-:2%\2/+.@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1NNZNS0rK/P9frU6lztKgwEAtQk3XSCtGX9fKSDXGSF9bz@H/fxM/bQNbYwA)

If we didn’t need to bother with rounding correctly, it could be much smaller:

```
&~$~90p0&X&-\/-.@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1NNZNS0rK/P9frU6lztKgwEAtQk03Rl9Xz@H/fzM/bUtbEyMA)

`-\/-`

Comment: I think this fails to round, and instead truncates. For example, it returns 0 for `3N+1=3` when it should round 2/3 up to 1

Comment: Fixed <padding>

Comment: For rounding, you can double the numerator before dividing, add the quotient to itself mod 2, and then divide the sum of that by 2, instead of doing the multiply by 10 thing

Comment: np, always happy to help

Answer (score 1):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 133 bytes

```c
N,d,y,x,a[9],o;f(*s){sscanf(s," %[0-9N] %c %d = %d",a,&o,&y,&x);d=!sscanf(a,"%d",&d)?1:d;N=(x-(o>43?-y:y))*2/d;printf("%d",N/2+N%2);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY/vboIwFMW/9ynuukBabMcfYYsy9A14AeOHppVJwsBQSCDGZ2eATtDYD@3N75x7ciq5zET@072nucxqdYBvXam0@Dhuupgp1rKGid1qz4owIZamZ62lyBOiGQZj5/BVvAdDgqEg6i/MBDMLZrbMbGioorebWzA8iKaiW3etwjgiDSfFxl9uebtuKbU8W4WnMs2rhIzO2PYWseHR8NJJkWUJkUdRglVJCnBGcLdquB3O@QYAM@gtIYKEXN9TXWmCcT9eEOp34FekOaFDxjUXQwwLcPv2y8E1o3ykwZx6L7136s/p8p@6D@ZgwMEQ4cyx@@Xcs313UFB5qOoyB2esbltoKvrwZw9NXR@ET@S93nBhUvynLMtG3R8)

This handles all spaces except between `d` and `N`.

[Removed wrong answer that rounds down]

Comment: some spaces can be removed

Comment: [124 bytes](https://tio.run/##bY/RboIwGIXv@xR/ukBaaAdF3KJMfANfwHjRtDJJGBgKCcT47AzQKSz2ov3znfOfnCquMpl/d29prrJaH@HLVDot3k9xp1nLGib3qwMrooQ4hl6MUTJPiGEYrL3PV7sDWAosDZv@wkwyu2B2y@yGRnpzN0uGB83WdKvXIjqXaV4lZGSkiMPFtnHbdcNb6gSedkUcCxpdOyWzLCHqJEtwKkUBLggeqwbuh3MeA2AGvSVCkJDbe64rQzDuxytC/Q78yDQndMi45WLYgQuir70YXBPKR7qc0uCl90HDKV38UTEzLwe8HCL8KRaf/iM7FIOCymNVlzn4Y3XPQc@isz8H6Nl1Jnyg4PWGgKcS/styPNT9Ag "C (clang) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Yabasic](http://www.yabasic.de), 142 bytes

An anonymous function that takes input as a string and outputs to the console.

```vb
Line Input""s$
dim n$(5)
k=token(s$,n$())
n$=n$(1)
If n$="N"n$=("1N")
?Int((Val(n$(5))-Val(n$(2)+"1")*Val(n$(3)))/Val(Left$(n$,Len(n$)-1))+.5)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Rc7BCsIwDAbge58ihB4atymd27F4EwajJ/E@tYMy7cRV0KevcQy9hC8/Ccm7O3WTP6f9@ABvQMNhhCq1Pjhowv0ZEScpLv4GQaqaxGDiOLigJplzQCSCNAxNoul5xKBFrgq1RRK7JkSljt1VzctULCwpQ420WtotEW2@bl0fJSd5yxeCpEITZeuaknWvmMBCxv8Z2ApmMbMW5T/9sfoA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 110 bits<sup>1</sup>, 13.75 [bytes](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md)

```
‛Nx*\=/ƒ∆qh.1+ṙ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=1#WyJ+PSIsIiIsIuKAm054KlxcPS/GkuKIhnFoLjEr4bmZIiwiIiwiISguKikgKy0tLT4gKFxcZCspXG4gTiArIDEgPSAzICAgICAgICAtLS0+IDJcbiBOIC0gMSA9IDUgICAgICAgIC0tLT4gNlxuMk4gKyAxID0gMyAgICAgICAgLS0tPiAxIFxuMk4gKyAxID0gNCAgICAgICAgLS0tPiAyIl0=)

Python rounding is a little goofy hence the `.1+ṙ` at the end.

Could be [9.125 bytes: `‛Nx*\=/ƒ∆q`](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=1#WyJ+PSIsIiIsIuKAm054KlxcPS/GkuKIhnEiLCIiLCIhKC4qKSArLS0tPiAoXFxkKylcbiBOICsgMSA9IDMgICAgICAgIC0tLT4gMlxuIE4gLSAxID0gNSAgICAgICAgLS0tPiA2XG4yTiArIDEgPSAzICAgICAgICAtLS0+IDEgXG4yTiArIDEgPSA0ICAgICAgICAtLS0+IDIiXQ==) if it wasn't for rounding.

### Explained

```
‛Nx*\=/ƒ∆qh.1+ṙ
‛Nx*            # Replace all N with x
    \=/         # split on equal sign
       ƒ∆q      # and solve the equation for x. Yes. There's a built in for it. 
          h.1+  # add 0.1 to the result to account for the fact that python seems to round down if <= 0.5 instead of < 0.5
              ṙ # round the answer as required
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala 3](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 168 bytes

```scala
import java.lang._
import scala.util.chaining._
val c:String=>Int=_.split("N|=").pipe(a=>(new Float(a(2))-new Float(a(1)))/new Float(a(0))).pipe(x=>math.round(x).toInt)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bY5BTsMwEEX3PcUoK49QDGlBQkiOxAapi3bDGlWD61JXrm0lkzZS4SRssgFxBY7CbTBJFxWwGv3358-f1_dak6NJ9xkeN0YzzMh6MC0bv6zhNkY4vDW8yq-_Puw2hophQzuSjvyTXIyOqD8hG7ZO6nXK297ckQN9c89VkqqcelYLWUdnWWTzZ5WhjDYaQaoU3uzhzgViQWKMmJ_qAhHPT8FFAkO0VeWWeC2r0PilaFFySC14_PcBIKZqdl5okRXzs0JNMsTRL5wX6uoPHv-_3ePLH_wylHTdML8B)

Comment: I thought `scala._` and `java.lang._` were imported by default

Answer (score 1):

## [Matlab],  91 bytes

this is the most resilient version.

assuming that s is the input string.

```
syms N;v=str2double(regexp(s,'(?<!\d)(\d)+(?!\d)','match'));round(solve(v(1)*N+v(2)==v(3)))
```

## [Matlab],  74 bytes

```
syms N;round(solve(str2double(s(1))*N+str2double(s(4))==str2double(s(6))))
```

but doesnt really work if for example Y was 2 digits (ie 10). I'll try to improve it a bit.

## [Matlab],  29 bytes

if the input was just the numbers and not a string

```
sym N;round(solve(d*N+Y==X))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Convex](https://github.com/GamrCorps/Convex), 19 bytes

```
S-®-?\d+"ô:d~\-\/mo
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87PK0ut@P8/WPfQOl37mBRtpcNbrFLqYnRj9HPz////r2Tkp6CtYKhgq2CiBAA)

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 45 bytes

```
<?=round((($s=$argn)[3].$s[5]-$s[9])/-$s[0]);
```

Run with `echo '<input>' | php -nF <filename>` or [Try it online](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxr4go4BLJbEoPU/BVkHd0E9BW8EQyDJWt1bQ11fwLy0pKC1RMNLjAnKQVemCVZmiqDJDVWWE3SxDHKpM0G20t@Oysbctyi/NS9HQ0FAptgXr0Yw2jtVTKY42jdUFkpaxmvog2iBW05rr/38A).

This requires that `d` always be given, and that the string is the same length each time, e.g.:

- `N + 1 = 3` *won't* work, but `1N + 1 = 3` *will* work.
- `1N +1 =3` *won't* work, but `1N + 1 = 3` *will* work.

Answer (score 0):

## J, 26 Bytes

```
<.({.%~{:-1&{)".>0 2 4{cut
```

Note that the result for N is floored (not rounded), so for the last test case it returns 1 instead of 2. If this is unacceptable I will change the answer.

Input should be of the form `'d N +-Y = X'`

#### Explanation:

```
   cut '10 N +2 = 23'  NB. Split on whitespace
┌──┬─┬──┬─┬──┐
│10│N│+2│=│23│
└──┴─┴──┴─┴──┘
   0 2 4{cut '10 N +2 = 23'  NB. Choose relevant portions
┌──┬──┬──┐
│10│+2│23│
└──┴──┴──┘
   ".>0 2 4{cut '10 N +2 = 23'  NB. Eval each
10 2 23
   ({.%~{:-1&{)".>0 2 4{cut'10 N +2 = 23'  NB. Compute (x-y)/d
2.1
   <.({.%~{:-1&{)".>0 2 4{cut'10 N +2 = 23'  NB. Floor
2
```

Answer (score 0):

### C# (149 Bytes)

```
s=>(int)Math.Round(((s=s.Replace(" ",""))[s.Length-1]-48-((s.Contains("-")?-1:1)*(s.Split(new[]{'+','-'})[1][0]-48)))/(decimal)(s[0]=='N'?1:s[0]-48))
```

Craptacular bloated C# solution. Guess I could've ported the Java solution but I try not to look at others' stuff before posting mine, so here we are.

[Try it Online](https://tio.run/##jY4xT8MwEIXn@FecvMSmcSBQJNSQdkBiaivUDqiKMhjHSi0lTpRzQKjqbw9uRQcW4C2ne/fd3VMoVNvrcUBjK9h@otNNSoKTSDe81UaBqiUivPRt1cuGHEjw7aOTzpf31pSwksYyTgI/DZ4Hqx7R9f5gBMa6OewggxGzOfMdX0m3jzftYEvGGGYYb3RXS6UZBRpRynmO8VLbyu1FUojpg/BU/NRa518go4LyhUhmCb/y9rarjWNWf@TFIZyEUSjCI8@TIr85bXLOr1mplWlkzRl6M8vCdbhIZngBxjQgcJb/gG2t49feOL00VrMdo2uYQOLD3/lY6e@gOIP3f4G3P07Cv9DpBT2S4/gF)

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 66 bytes

```ruby
->s{a,_,b,_,c=s.split.map &:to_f;((s[?+]?c-b:c+b)/(a+0**a)).round}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1664OlEnXicJiJNti/WKC3IyS/RyEwsU1KxK8uPTrDU0iqPttWPtk3WTrJK1kzT1NRK1DbS0EjU19YryS/NSav8XKKRFK/kpaCsYKtgqGCvFckEFdMECpjABIwwlcBETpdj/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## awk, 48 bytes

```
awk -F'[ N]' '{printf("%.f",($6-$4)/($1?$1:1))}'
```

Use cases:

```
echo "N + 1 = 3" | awk -F'[ N]' '{printf("%.f",($6-$4)/($1?$1:1))}'

echo "N - 1 = 5" | awk -F'[ N]' '{printf("%.f",($6-$4)/($1?$1:1))}'

echo "2N + 1 = 3" | awk -F'[ N]' '{printf("%.f",($6-$4)/($1?$1:1))}'

echo "2N + 1 = 4" | awk -F'[ N]' '{printf("%.f",($6-$4)/($1?$1:1))}'
```

Extra case:

```
echo "3N + 1 = 11" | awk -F'[ N]' '{printf("%.f",($6-$4)/($1?$1:1))}'
```

Output: 3

Answer (score 0):

### PHP, 83 Bytes

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRoKCSWJReZqtk5KegrWCoYKtgomRtbweUsy3KL81L0dBQSbZNrSjIyU9J1VBSUNIBK9fUjDaJ1QVKRRvG6gFJo1hNTX0Q1yDW1tbP3tCquDSpuKQIIqJjoKNrqKlp/f8/AA)

[Try it online2](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRoKCSWJReZqtk5KegrWCoYKtgomRtbweUsy3KL81L0dDQUEm2Ta0oyMlPSdVQUlDSAavX1Iw2idUFSkUbxuoBSaNYTU19ENcg1tbWz97Qqrg0qbikCCKiY6Cja6ipqWOgaf3/PwA)

For some reason **`round`** does not round to the closest integer on tio run, on this version the solution has some extra bytes **(87 Bytes)**

**Code**

```
<?=round(($c=explode(" ",$argv))[4]-($c[1].$c[2]))/($c[0]==N?1:substr($c[0],0,-1));
```

**Explanation**

```
//ecuation structure xN sign c = m
//array structure like ["xN","sign", "c", "=", "m"]
round(                         //round the result
(                              //first element of the ecuation
   $c=explode(" ",$argv))[4]   //explode the string and get the 4th value
   -                           //substract, php accepts (1-(-1)) so, 
                               //it can ve solved like this
   ($c[1].$c[2])               //concat the sign with c
)
/                              //divide by x
($c[0]==N?1:substr($c[0],0,-1) //if the first element xN it's N
                               //divide by 1, else remove N and divide
);
```

**Question**

About negative numbers, my code should work for an equation like `-xN +- c = m`, but when you are considering a `x = -1`, the input will be `-N +- c = m` or `-1N +- c = m`?

Answer (score 0):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 90 bytes

```r
-round(eval(parse(t=gsub("=","-",gsub("\\dN","",s<-scan(,"")))))/(gsub("N.*$","",s):1)[1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/X7covzQvRSO1LDFHoyCxqDhVo8Q2vbg0SUPJVklHSVdJB8KJiUnxA/KVdIptdIuTE/M0gGxNENDXgCjw09NSgSjQtDLUjDaM1fyvZOGnoK1gqWCrYKLE9R8A)

Assumes `d` is present as per the spec.
Probably not the shortest option - I am sure there are better regex.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` : safe division without branching ternary condition

```
echo 'N + 1 = 3' | 

gawk '$__=sprintf("%.f",($5-($2$3))/(_+=$_)^!!_)' 
mawk '{printf("%.f",($5-($2$3))/(_+=$_)^!!_)}'
```

---

```
2
```

---

```
echo '2N + 1 = 4' | 

nawk '$!NF=sprintf("%.f",($5-($2$3))/(_+=$!_)^!!_)'
```

---

```
2
```